# jQuery select option show / hide for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, select, hide, show

Hi I have this piece of code for show and hide elements by select option, which works great for 1 element, but if I use it with more elements it doesn't work correct anymore. How can I modify it so it works for each element apart?

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var $targets = $(".open_times");

    $(".pr_opener").change(function () {
        var i = $('option:selected', this).index();
        $targets.show().eq(i).hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yv4g/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify it to:

```
$(".pr_opener").change(function () {
    $(this).parent().next('div.open_times').toggle( this.value == 'Open' );
});
```

Also, you need to fix the markup (you aren't closing any of the `<select>` elements properly)

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yv4g/3/)

Answer (score 1):

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/JLAQg/)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var $targets = $(".open_times");

    $(".pr_opener").change(function () {
        var i = $('option:selected', this).text();
        if (i=='Open') {
            $(this).closest("li").next(".open_times").show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest("li").next(".open_times").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the event propogate up to the `ul` then handle it.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#pr_times ul").on("change",function () {
        $(".open_times", this).toggle();
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6yv4g/5/